# MonoTouch: adhoc build deploys only if I enable debugging

Tags: xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

I have an app that I have deployed the last 2 years from MonoDevelop. The app has 2 versions with different bundle IDs and therefore 2 provisions profiles. Previously I have switched bundle IDs, deployed and everything has been working great.

After the latest upgrade of MonoDevelop/MonoTouch (3.0.4.7/6.0.2) I can't get this to work anymore work for ad-hoc builds built using LLVM and no debugging enabled. Since it has been a long development time, I am not sure if it is caused by Monodevelop/MonoTouch changes or my projects changes.

The weird thing is that if I check the "enable debugging" of the release build, everything deploys fine. It then logs a warning saying "Conflicting --debug and --llvm options. Soft-debugging is disabled." which seems to indicate that enabling the debug option has no effect?

So the question is: Why does the app only deploy to the device correctly if I enable debugging on the release build?

The only change in terms of 3rd party content is that we have added the new Admob bindings from here: 
https://github.com/dalexsoto/AlexTouch.GoogleAdMobAds, but to my knowledge these don't need any special parameters to be included in release builds.

I have zipped a distribution build without debugging and sent to Apple for approval but I think it will have the same problem as my adhoc builds and therefore will be rejected. Hope some Mono gurus have some insight in this!

Here is the complete log including installation and first launch:

```
    Sep 30 23:58:23 Christer-sin-iPhone librariand[5904] <Error>: client process 619 does not have a valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement
    Sep 30 23:58:24 Christer-sin-iPhone ubd[5905] <Notice>:
    Sep 30 23:58:27 Christer-sin-iPhone librariand[5904] <Notice>: MMe quota status changed: under quota
    Sep 30 23:58:28 Christer-sin-iPhone installd[5365] <Error>: 0x2ffa2000 handle_uninstall: Uninstall requested by SpringBoard
    Sep 30 23:58:28 Christer-sin-iPhone installd[5365] <Error>: 0x2ffa2000 MobileInstallationUninstall_Server: Uninstalling com.myapp
    Sep 30 23:58:29 Christer-sin-iPhone ubd[5905] <Error>: Sep 30 23:58:29  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorTrusted]
    Sep 30 23:58:30 Christer-sin-iPhone installd[5365] <Error>: 0x30b000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Xcode (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1e5851c0 [0x3b76a100]>{type = mutable set, count = 18,
    entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x3b7569f4 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "CFBundlePackageType"}
    1 : <CFString 0x1e57a800 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "BuildMachineOSBuild"}
    2 : <CFString 0x3b757a44 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "CFBundleResourceSpecification"}
    3 : <CFString 0x1e57b060 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTPlatformBuild"}
    4 : <CFString 0x3b754794 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTCompiler"}
    5 : <CFString 0x3b756564 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "CFBundleSignature"}
    6 : <CFString 0x3b757224 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTSDKName"}
    7 : <CFString 0x1e5782a0 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "NSBundleResolvedPath"}
    8 : <CFString 0x3b753eb4 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"}
    10 : <CFString 0x3b75be84 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTXcode"}
    13 : <CFString 0x3b75beb4 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"}
    16 : <CFString 0x3b759304 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"}
    17 : <CFString 0x1e57b0a0 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTXcodeBuild"}
    18 : <CFString 0x1e5782c0 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "UIStatusBarTintParameters"}
    19 : <CFString 0x3b757e54 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTPlatformVersion"}
    20 : <CFString 0x3b75abf4 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTPlatformName"}
    21 : <CFString 0x3b75bc84 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"}
    22 : <CFString 0x1e57b080 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTSDKBuild"}
    }
    Sep 30 23:58:31 Christer-sin-iPhone mobile_installation_proxy[5908] <Error>: 0x3c390b88 MobileInstallationSlowLookupBreak: MobileInstallationBrowse was called without specifying an options dictionary containing kLookupReturnAttributesKey. This usage is inefficient and may cause performance problems. Break on MobileInstallationSlowLookupBreak to debug.
    Sep 30 23:58:31 Christer-sin-iPhone mobile_installation_proxy[5908] <Error>: 0x3c390b88 MobileInstallationSlowLookupBreak: Existing options dictionary: <CFBasicHash 0x1cd81790 [0x3b76a100]>{type = mutable dict, count = 1,
    entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0xa51a0 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "RequestProxiedFor"} = <CFString 0x1cd818f0 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "mtouch"}
    }
    Sep 30 23:58:38 Christer-sin-iPhone installd[5365] <Error>: 0x2ffa2000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/NDC2010.app" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
    Sep 30 23:58:38 Christer-sin-iPhone installd[5365] <Error>: 0x2ffa2000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.myapp
    Sep 30 23:58:39 Christer-sin-iPhone installd[5365] <Error>: Sep 30 23:58:39  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
    Sep 30 23:58:41 Christer-sin-iPhone timed[5457] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Received timezone "Europe/Oslo" from "Location"
    Sep 30 23:58:41 Christer-sin-iPhone timed[5457] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Current mcc: '242' simulated:'0'.
    Sep 30 23:58:41 Christer-sin-iPhone timed[5457] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Not setting time zone to Europe/Oslo from Location
    Sep 30 23:58:42 Christer-sin-iPhone installd[5365] <Error>: 0x2ffa2000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.43s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 4.41s; LS Sync: 0.12s; Overall: 4.96s
    Sep 30 23:58:42 Christer-sin-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[5911] Builtin profile: syncdefaultsd (sandbox)
    Sep 30 23:58:44 Christer-sin-iPhone installd[5365] <Error>: 0x2ffa2000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Xcode (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1e692820 [0x3b76a100]>{type = mutable set, count = 18,
    entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x3b7569f4 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "CFBundlePackageType"}
    1 : <CFString 0x1e58c4a0 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "BuildMachineOSBuild"}
    2 : <CFString 0x3b757a44 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "CFBundleResourceSpecification"}
    3 : <CFString 0x1e578200 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTPlatformBuild"}
    4 : <CFString 0x3b754794 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTCompiler"}
    5 : <CFString 0x3b756564 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "CFBundleSignature"}
    6 : <CFString 0x3b757224 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTSDKName"}
    7 : <CFString 0x1e5761a0 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "NSBundleResolvedPath"}
    8 : <CFString 0x3b753eb4 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"}
    10 : <CFString 0x3b75be84 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTXcode"}
    13 : <CFString 0x3b75beb4 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"}
    16 : <CFString 0x3b759304 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"}
    17 : <CFString 0x1e578240 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTXcodeBuild"}
    18 : <CFString 0x1e57a970 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "UIStatusBarTintParameters"}
    19 : <CFString 0x3b757e54 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTPlatformVersion"}
    20 : <CFString 0x3b75abf4 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTPlatformName"}
    21 : <CFString 0x3b75bc84 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"}
    22 : <CFString 0x1e578220 [0x3b76a100]>{contents = "DTSDKBuild"}
    }
    Sep 30 23:59:14 Christer-sin-iPhone NDC2010[5915] <Warning>: MonoTouch: Failed to open /private/var/mobile/Applications/38C5A938-BBDF-4BCD-AD25-1220671DDF63/NDC2010.app/MonoTouchDebugConfiguration.txt
    Sep 30 23:59:14 Christer-sin-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[5915] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
    Sep 30 23:59:14 Christer-sin-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[5915] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/38C5A938-BBDF-4BCD-AD25-1220671DDF63 (sandbox)
    Sep 30 23:59:15 Christer-sin-iPhone NDC2010[5915] <Warning>: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
    Sep 30 23:59:15 Christer-sin-iPhone NDC2010[5915] <Critical>: Terminating runtime due to unhandled exception
    Sep 30 23:59:16 Christer-sin-iPhone ReportCrash[5917] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process NDC2010[5915]
    Sep 30 23:59:16 Christer-sin-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.myapp[0x9886][5915]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.myapp[0x9886]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
    Sep 30 23:59:16 Christer-sin-iPhone backboardd[52] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.myapp[0x9886]' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
    Sep 30 23:59:16 Christer-sin-iPhone ReportCrash[5917] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
```

Comment: As the logs implies the crash report likely contains the clues you're looking for. `<Critical>: Terminating runtime due to unhandled exception` followed by `<Notice>: Formulating crash report for process NDC2010[5915]`

Comment: @poupou I opened a bug, hope you can take a look at it, Bug# 7557 Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update:

This has been fixed on the latest [GoogleAdMobAds Bindings](https://github.com/dalexsoto/AlexTouch.GoogleAdMobAds)

---

Yes, your problem is Admob Binding, there is a problem retrieving sizes on release builds (thanks btw :) ), this class is the problem  `GADAdSizeCons`, so doing something like this

```
var ad = new GADBannerView(GADAdSizeCons.Banner, new PointF(0,0))
{
    AdUnitID = "Your Id",
    RootViewController = this
};
```

Will crash only on `release builds on real device`, I opened a bug today about this on Xamarin so I hope this will get fixed soon :)

## So here is the Workaround

Ok so while we wait you need to manually create the `GADSize struct` by hand, for example if you need an iPhone Portrait banner you would do this

```
GADAdSize gsize = new GADAdSize()
{
    flags = 0,
    size = new System.Drawing.SizeF(320, 50)
};

var ad = new GADBannerView(gsize, new PointF(0,0))
{
    AdUnitID = "Your Id",
    RootViewController = this
};
```

Here are the values

> **Banner:**       **Flags**: 0    **Size**: {Width=**320**, Height=**50**}
>
> **FullBanner:**   **Flags**: 0    **Size**: {Width=**468**, Height=**60**}
>
> **Leaderboard:**  **Flags**: 0    **Size**: {Width=**728**, Height=**90**}
>
> **MediumRectangle:**  **Flags**: 0    **Size**: {Width=**300**, Height=**250**}
>
> **Skyscraper:**   **Flags**: 0    **Size**: {Width=**120**, Height=**600**}

The downside of this workaround is that you can only create the above sizes, if you try to create a `Custom Size` you won't get an Ad served to you

Hope this Helps

Alex